# Uglify for removing console logs works on and off

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, uglifyjs, vuejs3

I have a Vue3 app. I am using UglifyJS to remove console.logs from Prod envs. It works sometimes, sometimes it doesn't. I have to try rebuilding again and again to make it work. Is there something missing in my config?

```
    //vue.config.js
    const UglifyJSPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin")
    .
    .
    .
    configureWebpack: config => {
        //development added just for local testing
        //the variable is set, checked it using console.log
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") { 
            // mutate config for production...
            config.optimization.minimizer = [
                new UglifyJSPlugin({
                    test: /\.vue(\?.*)?$/i,
                    uglifyOptions: {
                        compress: {
                            drop_console: true
                        }
                    }
                })
          ]
      }
  }
```

It only sometimes works, as in all my console.logs are hidden but not always. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I have deliberately set it to development because I want to test it out before I commit it. So with this flag, it should work for a local dev, right?

Comment: I tried a prod build, the console.logs are still there.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one with the help of a fellow Vue dev from their official forums.

```
productionSourceMap: true
```

In your Vue config should fix it.